# How to get number of nodes inside a xml file?

Tags: php, xml

Having a xml file so formed:

```
<book id="1">
  <chapter id="1">
    ...
  </chapter>
  <chapter id="2">
    ...
  </chapter>
  <chapter id="3">
    ...
  </chapter>
</book>
```

How i can count nodes inside ... ?
In example above, the function should be turn 3 as result becouse present three nodes.

**NOTE:**
I access to  ...  so:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($filename);
$book = $xpath->query("//book[@id='1']")->item(0);
```

Comment: Did you try using `xpath` or `xquery`?

Comment: i using domxpath.

Comment: @MarcelloImpastato : Please check my edited answer

Comment: Thank, it work too so. I tried too using "evalutate". Both method work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as:

Refer: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName('chapter')->length;
```

Unless you can use this:

```
$xpath->evaluate('count(//book/chapter');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function xml2array($xmlObject, $out = array()) {
    foreach ((array) $xmlObject as $index => $node)
        $out[$index] = ( is_object($node) ) ? xml2array($node) : $node;

    return $out;
}

$a = '<book>
<chapter id = "1">
...
</chapter>
<chapter id = "2">
...
</chapter>
<chapter id = "3">
...
</chapter>
</book>';
$a = simplexml_load_string($a);
$array=xml2array($a);
echo count($array['chapter']);
```

**EDIT**

Using `DOMXpath` try this

```
echo $book = $xpath->query("//book[@id='1']/chapter")->length;
```